# Infinite call of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, web, react-context

This piece of code calls "Market" component infinite times. How can i fix that? (I wanna pass props to my market component with UserConsumer (ContextAPI))

```
function App() {

  return (

    <div className="container">
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Loginpage} />
        <UserConsumer>
          {
            value => {
              return(
                <Route exact path="/loggedin" component={() => <Market state_of_context={value} />} />
              )
            }
          }
        </UserConsumer>
      </Switch>

    </div>

  );
}
```

Comment: Consumers need to be rendered into the component tree. You can't render something from a handler function. Also what you are currently doing is having jsx as a statement in a handler. That makes absolutely no sense at all. The correct way to do this would be to have some state in the component that renders the provider and update it with the data from the response. Also the render function provided to a consumer should return valid react elements.

Comment: @trixn understood sir, thanks :)

Comment: @trixn i have 1 little question too. I added state_ prop to my component to get state of another component. But when i call it in route, it calls my component infinite times. I am providing code to question. Can you check it out? Thanks.

Comment: components are not called, they are rendered by react. You should really try to first fully understand the fundamental concepts before you get your hands on a real application instead of trying to guess your way to a solution. There are plenty of good tutorials out there.

Comment: I mean, because of i said "call" instead of "render" i should stop doing my project and study fundamentals of react?

Comment: @trixn imagine, if i didnt know fundametals of react, would i be able to come that far sir?

Comment: It's more the fact that you tried to use a consumer outside of a component body/render function. Also now you edited your question to be a completely different one. This is not a chat room. Questions are supposed to be helpful for other people with the same question in the future.

Comment: If `Market` is the component that actually needs the context, why don't you use the consumer inside of that instead of wrapping the route into one. The route doesn't need to re-render when the context changes.

Comment: @trixn thanks sir. I will update my code